# Media Recorder Exception Issue

Tags: android, media, android-mediarecorder

I have a strange problem with the Android media recorder. On **a few** devices the following code fails in a way that I do not understand:

```
    if (mRecorder != null)
    {
      try
      {
          mRecorder.stop();
          mRecorder.release();
          camera.lock();
          mRecorder = null;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          ; // ignore
      }
    }
```

What seems to happen, is that some of the methods in the try block fails, with no exception being caught, and the method is never finished. Has anybody any idea as to what may be happening? As I have no access to the devices in question, I am unable to debug this issue.

Comment: camera.lock(); looks suspicious to me. why you having it?

Answer (score 0):

Above code snippet is correct only but before doing this you must need to ensure with below points :

- MediaRecorder is already stopped and your trying again to stop it :    Exception
- If MediaRecorder is already released and you are trying again to release it : Exception
- Camera is released and you are trying to lock it again : Exception

Comment: OK. But even if one of these Exceptions where thrown, it would be cathed by the catch block, and the method would continue (?). In this case, the method is never finished.

Comment: never finish means what ?? try to print something inside catch block.

Comment: and if runtime exception came try catch will not be able to work in that cases ...

Comment: Could it be that some media recorder error resulted in the onError() being called - and NOT an EXception being thrown? Could that be the reason that this method is never finished?

Comment: And what do you mean by " if runtime exception came try catch will not be able to work in that cases" ?

Comment: I know that this method never finishes because I show a message immediately after the code shown in the example. And it is NOT shown.

Comment: where you are trying to show a message ?? Runtime exception can occurred as you are accessing camera hardware device.

Comment: In order to keep the shown code as simple as possible, I did not include the code line where a message  is being shown. But it is done immediately after the catch block. In cases where this method fails, it is never shown. What do you mean by saying "Runtime exception can occurred as you are accessing camera hardware device." Will they not cause an Exception? What will happen if a Runtime Exception occurs?

Comment: RuntimeException case your further code won't be executed and application will be stopped working. more details go through this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html link and check run time exception for lock() method.

Comment: I am getting confused. Many of the Camera methods throw an IOException or a RuntimeException. Why are they NOT catched by my catch block? (I am back to square one.) Why do you say that the application will be stopped by a RuntimeException, when it is catched by the catch block?

Comment: See i can't explain all the details here you need to google and explore more about exceptions like 1.Checked Exceptions 2. Unchecked Exceptions. Only unchecked exception we can handle through try catch blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Arfin. But I am no wiser, even after having done a lot of googling on the matter.

Comment: My guess is camera.lock() is only giving you the exception. If you are recording only once you can do lock() method inside onDestroy or else you have a option to restart the recording again (i.e initializing again all the resources you must need to handle lock() properly.